# Storing a simple array in Realm without creating a managed List in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have an array of data that doesn't need to be a managed List, meaning I don't need Realm to create a new model for the items with links and the ability to query on the items, etc. I just want a simple array, typically of primitives that don't inherit from Object anyway, that will be persisted with my main object.

The only solution I can think of is to use NSData and NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver. Is that the best/only way to do this? Should I just use List even if I don't think I'll need it — what's the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm doesn't support arrays of primitives (although that functionality is coming soon), so the most straightforward solution is to use a `List` filled with model objects that just wrap your primitives. There's nothing wrong with archiving to and from `NSData` and storing the data in your Realm model, though, if you feel that better suits your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I decided to deal with this:

```
var instructions: [String] {
  get {
    if _instructions == nil {
      _instructions = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: instructionsData) as? [String]
    }
    return _instructions!
  }
  set {
    instructionsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
    _instructions = newValue
  }
}
fileprivate var _instructions: [String]? = nil
dynamic var instructionsData = Data()

override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
  return ["instructions", "_instructions"]
}
```

That way I can use the array as I normally would and still have it persisted in a simple way (without having to create an actual `List` and having to manage a bunch of new models/objects).